# Convert Hexadecimal MAC address to user readable formatting (Python)

Tags: python, macos, hex, bin

I'm receiving from the socket a MAC address in this format:
0024e865a023 (hex converted from binary with received-string.encode("hex"))

I would like to convert it to a user readable format like this :
00-24-e8-65-a0-23

Any easy way to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can break apart the MAC address into an array of each block, and then join them on `-`:

```
mac = '0024e865a023'
blocks = [mac[x:x+2] for x in xrange(0, len(mac), 2)]
macFormatted = '-'.join(blocks)
```

Comment: just the x before range is to much, but edits need at least 6 characters ... ;)

Comment: @John Not sure what you're saying; `xrange` is just `range` in Python 3, if that's the problem you're having. They renamed `xrange` to `range` and got rid of the old version of `range`

Comment: your right. i didnt work with Python 2 and in First Moment i thought it was a typing error. 
Anyway it solved my Problem too. Thanks!